# Rebuilding Node and Syncing with snapshot

Tags: node, bootstrapping

I had to spin up a new node...used a snapshot. How long should it take sync?

Comment: I don't believe this is a good question because it's too vague. The factor in time depends on what snapshot was used (ie. how far off from the latest block), what hardware is used(especially in IO speeds) to run the new node. Also it's not clear if the question has to do with importing the snapshot or actually getting the node to bootstrap, I assume the latter?

Comment: I imported a snapshot...and bootstrapped the node.